# Projection using async delegate/lambda

Tags: c#, async-ctp, async-await, c#-5.0

The following code will not compile against the Async CTP in Visual Studio 2010:

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(async x =>
{
    await TaskEx.Delay(100);
    return 5;
});
```

The compilation error is as follows:

```
Test.cs(40,13): error CS1928: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select<TSource,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,TResult>)' has some invalid arguments
Test.cs(40,49): error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'lambda expression' to 'System.Func<int,int>'
```

However, by my read, the following should occur here:

- The overload `IEnumerable<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TResult> selector)` should be used.
- As the `.Range(1, 5)` is `IEnumerable<int>`, `TSource` is `int`
- Making the lambda async, taking an `int` and returning an `int` should produce a `Task<int>`, which is what `TResult` should be.

**I don't see a syntax issue here. What is the problem?**

Note that I cannot use VS11 yet because my main application requires Azure tools.

**EDIT:** This works fine with `msbuild` at the command line, but not in VS2010. It seems that at the command line, the VS11 compiler is being used even though I'm targeting .NET 4.0, whereas VS2010 uses its own in-process compiler. Does anyone know how to swap out the compiler that VS2010 uses?

Comment: outside of changing TaskEx to Task, works fine in my LINQPad and VS11, so looks like a CTP bug?

Comment: not sure i understand the Azure tools limitation?  i installed the azure sdk via nuget in my vs11 beta projects fine - am I misunderstanding?

Comment: FWIW, you might be able to workaround this in the CTP by doing something like 'Func<int, Task<int>> foo = async x => ..' and then pass that to the Select?

Comment: @JamesManning Can you actually deploy to the cloud using VS11 with the NuGet, by doing Publish?

Comment: @JamesManning Unfortunately, the example is contrived (though it definitely will not compile against the CTP) and in reality there's anonymous types involved. So, I need to rely on the compiler to get the types right.

Comment: @JamesManning https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/vs11/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works in my LINQPad (VS11 Beta installed on the machine)

[image]