# Create a thread that starts multiple other threads

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, concurrency

I'm looking to request data from different endpoints, inside a controller method. I only want to return the View() when all those requests are done. Can this be done, and how can this be done?

Right now I'm doing something close to this

```
class GetDemData
{
    int count = 0;
    int requestsCompleted = 0;

    List<string> addresses = new List<string>();

    public void AddDataToBeCollected(string address)
    {
        adresses.Add(address);
    }

    public void CollectData()
    {
        foreach (string address in addresses)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:1337/");
            client.GetAsync(address).ContinueWith(
                getTask =>
                    {
                        if (getTask.IsCanceled)
                        {
                            error();
                        }
                        else if(getTask.IsFaulted)
                        {
                            error();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            requestsCompleted++;
                            checkFinished();
                        }
                    }
            );
        }
    }

    public void checkFinished()
    {
        if (count == requestsCompleted)
        {
            // All data collected
        }
    }

    public void error()
    {
        // yes error
    }
}
```

And this is my controller

```
public ActionResult GetData()
{
    var data = new GetDemData();
    // fill data with addresses
    data.CollectData();

    return View();
}
```

The problem is, since everything is done async, the View is returned immediately. How can I make sure the View is only returned when I collect all the data?

Comment: Why aren't you using await?

Comment: I'm fairly new to C#, if you could give me an example? I want all the requests to be done at the same time if possible

Comment: `await` does not force the calling thread to block necessarily. It's just a compiler trick to force a rewrite of the method into continuations.

Comment: In fact with the code that both I and Tejs wrote, it should be single threaded. You actually want a concurrent/asynchronous/single threaded application for best performance in this case (I/O bound operations).

Comment: I mean Brian Reischl actually...not Tejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class GetDemData
{

    List<string> addresses = new List<string>();

    public void AddDataToBeCollected(string address)
    {
        adresses.Add(address);
    }

    public Task CollectData()
    {
                var webclient = new WebClient();
                var tasks = from address in addresses
                            select webclient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(address);

                return Task.WhenAll(tasks.Select(
                            async (downloadTask) => 
                            {
                                 var result = await downloadTask;
                                 //Do somthing with result
                            }));
    }

}


public async Task<ActionResult> GetData()
{
    var data = new GetDemData();
    // fill data with addresses
    await data.CollectData();

    return View();
}
```

Comment: You cannot use `Select` to project to an async lambda. (You don't even need an async lambda here, just select out the task itself and unwrap the call to `WhenAll`.)  The type of the delegate cannot be inferred.  Also, it's `DownloadStringTaskAsync` not `DownloadStringAsyncTask`

Comment: @Servy, you need it to do a something with the result. PS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712655/projection-using-async-delegate-lambda

Comment: He needs to do something when they have all finished, not when each operation finishes, that means awaiting, or adding a continuation to, the result of `WhenAll`.  If he had some work done after each download completed then sure (although you're still not doing that correctly), but he doesn't.

Comment: `WebClient.DownloadStringAsyncTask` is a pure function. Unless you do something with the result you might as well not invoke it (unless the target server is actually using a GET for operations, in which case, I cannot be held responsible for people abusing the HTTP spec).

Comment: It's not clear what the OP is doing with it, based on his code.  It could be that he's only interested in the errored results, it could be that he's using the results but didn't show it, in which case you'd still need to provide such an opportunity in *a way that would compile*.  Personally I'd have the method just return the aggregated results, assuming that the calling code is going to do something with it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to keep a reference to the `Task` instances, and then call `.Wait()` on that task to force the thread to block until those requests are done. For example:

```
var mainThread = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
      {
             var tasks = addresses.Select(x => Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                 {
                       // Do your download stuff for one address

                       return "someContent";
                 });

            Task.WaitAll(tasks); // Blocks all the minor tasks, waits until they all complete

            return tasks.Select(x => x.Result).ToList(); // You may observe exceptions here
      });

var allResults = mainThread.Result; // List<string>, blocks until all tasks are complete
                                    // can also observe exceptions here

return View(allResults);
```

Comment: This is synchronously waiting on all of the asynchronous operations.  You shouldn't be doing that.  Either the code should be entirely asynchronous from top to bottom, or it should just use synchronous operations all the way down.

Comment: Correct, but the OP was asking how to wait on the threads. From his example, he's not using MVC Async Controllers either.

Comment: The OP may have asked for it, but that's still not the proper solution to the problem.  He doesn't know better, so explain why he shouldn't be doing that.

Comment: We should be guiding those down the path of threadless asynchronous operations.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use simple async/await if you want to fire all the requests at once. eg, if you used `await` inside your loop it would still fire one request at a time, wait for it to complete, then fire the next request. Instead you have to fire all the requests, collect the resulting `Task` objects, and wait for all of them to complete.

```
public Task CollectData()
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach (string address in addresses)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://example.com:1337/");

        //Note we're collecting the resulting Task objects here
        //We're actually getting the task from the continuation, which is a little bit weird
        //Alternatively, you could break this into another method that uses await internally
        var task = client.GetAsync(address).ContinueWith(
            getTask =>
                {
                    if (getTask.IsCanceled)
                    {
                        error();
                    }
                    else if(getTask.IsFaulted)
                    {
                        error();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        requestsCompleted++;
                        checkFinished();
                    }
                }
        );
        tasks.Add(task);
    }

    //Return a single task that completes when all the subtasks are done
    return Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
}
```

Controller...

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetData()
{
    var data = new GetDemData();
    // fill data with addresses
    var task = data.CollectData();
    await task;
    return View();
}
```

Update, a somewhat cleaner way to do it by using a separate method that fires just one request. Also, I just noticed that you're not using `HttpClient` correctly - it is `IDisposable` and also contains an internal request pool so it should be reused rather than created and destroyed per-request.

```
public async Task CollectData()
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        foreach (string address in addresses)
        {
            tasks.Add(ExecuteSingleRequest(client, address));
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
    }
}

private async Task ExecuteSingleRequest(HttpClient client, Uri uri)
{
    try
    {
        var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //This is lazy example code, do real error handling here and don't catch Exception
    }
}
```

Comment: Erm...you should really be using the async'ness for your error handling.

Comment: I was just copying what he had there, since I don't really know what he's trying to accomplish in the error handling. But I updated with a version that would do that.